# HERE SDK iOS. Map not loading

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I'm developing and iOS App with the HERE maps SDK using the positioning feature.

Everything was working fine until yesterday when I got the next error:

```
Task <08913090-BF88-4BE5-8195-938A5D757B03>.<2> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
Task <08913090-BF88-4BE5-8195-938A5D757B03>.<2> finished with error - code: -999
```

The map can't be loaded, but the search request is working.

I checked my Info.plist file and it contains the ATS exceptions stated by HERE:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>here.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Deployment target: iOS 10.0

Swift version: 4.0

I don't know what is wrong since I haven't modified anything about the network configuration and neither my HERE credentials.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem just now, I updated here SDK but the problem persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem yesterday and updated our iOS HERE SDK to version 3.6.

Now the Map is working correctly again.